# I've been reading a lot of books or I've read a lot of books?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

I want to say that I started reading a lot of books when I was a child and I continue to do so. So is the present perfect continuous the right tense or should it be the present perfect simple?

**I've been reading a lot of books since I was a child.**

Or

**I have read a lot of books since I was a child.**

I think **I've read** means I'm finished reading them and doesn't imply I still read a lot of books.

Doesn't **I've been reading** mean I'm still reading the same books as in I haven't finished them?

Comment: I think the Present Perfect Continuous is a bit over the top for such contexts. *I've been smoking a lot of cigarettes since I was a teenager* just sounds ridiculous. But *I've always read a lot of books, ever since I was a child* sounds fine to me. Not to be confused with *I've read a lot of books since I was a child,* which means something quite different.

Comment: In practice, the present perfect continuous implies a recent habit - _I've been reading a lot of Agatha Christie's books lately_. (It doesn't mean that I haven't finished any of them.)

Comment: You've written (1) “**I read a lot of books since**…” perhaps you meant to write: “**I've read a lot**...” (2) Please edit your question if you meant to use the Present perfect construction, i.e. (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following passage is from Grammarly [1](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/):

> *The present perfect tense is one of the common verb tenses in English, used to show an action that happened in the past that is directly related to the present, such as actions that are still continuing or that indicate a change over time.*

So **I have read a lot of books since I was a child** doesn't mean that I read the books and I now I don't read books anymore.

The following text is from Cambridge Dictionary [2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-continuous-i-have-been-working):

> ### Present perfect continuous: uses
>
> **Recent past activities**
>
> We use the present perfect continuous to talk about a finished activity in the recent past. Using the present perfect continuous focuses on the activity.
>
> We don’t give a specific time. Even though the activity is finished, we can see the result in the present:
>
> - **I’ve** just **been cleaning** the car. (The car is wet and clean.)**
> - It’**s been snowing**. (The ground is covered in snow.)**
> - What **have** you **been buying?**
>
> **One continuing event**
> We use the present perfect continuous for a single activity that began at a point in the past and is still continuing:
>
> - I’**ve been reading your book** – it’s great. (I’m still reading it.)
> - He’**s been living** in the village since 1995. (He is still living in the village.)
> - She **has been writing** her autobiography since 1987.
>
> **Repeated continuing events**
> We use the present perfect continuous to talk about repeated activities which started at a particular time in the past and are still continuing up until now:
>
> - I’**ve been going** to Spain on holiday every year since 1987.
> - I **haven’t been eating** much lunch lately. I’ve been going to the gym at lunchtimes.
> - She’**s been playing** tennis on and off for three years.
>
> **How long …?**
>
> We often use the present perfect continuous to ask and answer questions about the duration of an activity. We use the question *How long …* + present perfect continuous:
>
> **A:** *How long **have you been** waiting for me?*
>
> **B**: *About ten minutes. Not too long*. (I’ve been waiting for about ten minutes.)

So both your sentences **I have read a lot of books since I was a child** and **I've been reading a lot of books since I was a child** are correct.

Comment: The **edit** (not *edition*)  is visible in the review queue, I can approve or reject edits and I rejected yours because you should not guess what the OP wanted to write. I have left a comment beneath their post asking them to make any necessary change. You can wait to see if " I read" was a typo for "I have read" OR you can actually explain why "I read books ... since I was a child" is grammatically incorrect or nonstandard.

Comment: I see someone downvoted, so it's +1 from me because the quality of the answer doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

"I've been reading a lot of books.", to me, conveys the idea that you've *recently* read a lot of books with the implication that this is new trend for you.

With the full sentence you presented:
"I've been reading a lot of books since I was a child." seems awkward and contradictory. It's contradictory for the reason I listed above. It's additionally awkward because "since" can essentially mean "because". To make "since" unambiguously refer to time you can say "ever since"

Alternatively, "I read a lot of books since I was a child." seems to mean that you've read a large amount of books but it doesn't necessarily convey "and I continue to do so"

To convey both ideas, without changing the sentence structure too much, I'd probably say "Ever since I was a child, I've always read a lot of books"